# How do I get all requests in puma rack app?

Tags: ruby, rack, puma

I'm writing a dead-simple puma server,
and I keep getting 404 for every request.
How do I configure the '/' path **without** Sinatra?

I simply want to catch **all** requests.

```
#config.ru
module Moon
  class HelloWorldApp
    def call(env)
      [200, {}, 'Hello World']
    end
    def each(env=nil)
      env
    end
  end
end

run Rack::Cascade.new Moon::HelloWorldApp.new
```

I run it like this:

```
$ puma config.ru -p 9595
```

Use this curl:

```
$ curl http://0.0.0.0:9595/test
```

And get 404:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2015:22:49:25 +0300] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 - 0.0002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rack::Cascade` expects an explicit *array* of apps to be passed to the constructor (or at least something like an enumerable that responds to each and yields the apps). It then [calls `each` on this array](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.0/lib/rack/cascade.rb#L13) to get each app (it looks like you’ve hit the no method error and tried to work round it by adding an `each` method to your app).

Fix it by changing the `run` line to:

```
run Rack::Cascade.new [Moon::HelloWorldApp.new]
```

You will also need to change the body part of your returned array, it needs to be something that [responds to `each` and yields `String`s](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC#The_Body), the simplest way to fix that is to return an array:

```
[200, {}, ['Hello World']]
```